# Django not found : / with a View on set on it for non www?

Tags: django, heroku, dns, no-www, dnsimple

I'm running a Django app on Heroku using Dnsimple to point the domain to heroku. When I load http://example.com or https://example.com I get

"Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server."

I get the following log in my logs window:

2017-06-04T02:20:51.503765+00:00 app[web.1]: Not Found: /
2017-06-04T02:20:51.503784+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /

However I have the url supported and it works on example.com or www.example.com or https://www.example.com, or http://www.example.com :

supported URL "url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')"

The fact that I'm getting Logs in my server display makes me think it's not a config issue with dnsimple but I'm getting a log like the view isn't there on non www domains?

To add my heroku domains are

```
example.com = example.com.herokudns.com
*.example.com  =  wildcard.example.com.herokudns.com
www.example.com = www.example.com.herokudns.com
```

To add my Dnsimple configuration is  :

```
Domain          Record Type  DNS Target
──────────────  ───────────  ─────────────────────────────────
example.com      ALIAS/ANAME  example.com.herokudns.com
*.example.com    CNAME        wildcard.example.com.herokudns.com
www.example.com  CNAME        www.example.com.herokudns.com
```

Comment: You can check  `heroku domains` on console. Maybe you need to add wildcard domain (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)

Comment: I added my domains to my post, I have a wildcard domain currently which was an initial thought.

Comment: Simply adding domains on heroku not going to work you should set an ALIAS for `www` in your DNS settings within DnsSimple and point it to `www.example.com.herokudns.com`